# How to center form in parent div?

Tags: html, css

In my form, the lables/inputsare aligned with floats and fixed widths. Because of this, my labels have empty whitespace which makes it difficult to center the form in the parent div.

How can I center this form?

```css
#Form1Layout {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 10pt;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

#Form1Layout label {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 80px;
}

#Form1Layout input {
  width: 300px;
}

#Form1Layout label,
#Form1Layout input {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#Form1Layout br {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="Form1Layout">
    <label>User name:</label><input type="text" /><br>
    <label>Address:</label><input type="text" /><br>
    <label>Phone:</label><input type="text" /><br>
    <label></label><button class="My_Button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: missing a `#` from the very first css rule, also no style tags?

Comment: is there a reason not using `display: flex;` with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use flexboxes for that. Here is a quick example.

(I intentionnaly increased the height of the inputs to show you how it works).

```css
#Form1Layout {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 10pt;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

#Form1Layout > div {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

#Form1Layout label {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 80px;
}

#Form1Layout input {
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="Form1Layout">
    <div><label>User name:</label><input type="text" /></div>
    <div><label>Address:</label><input type="text" /></div>
    <div><label>Phone:</label><input type="text" /></div>
    <div><label></label><button class="My_Button">Submit</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but I think this has a similar issue. If I change the label width to 300px, then the whitespace in the labels makes the layout appear to be significantly off center. What is the best way to deal with this, just try to keep the label width to a minimum? And if the text size/contents changes, I'll have to be careful about adjusting the label width? It seems like this is a limitation of relying on fixed label widths for alignment.

Comment: Well of course if you create blank spaces, you see blank spaces ... My advice is that you either let the label handle its own width, or you set its width and you force it to make a carriage return when it is too long (and the flex will automatically align it with the input). But you can't create a blank space and expect not to see it ...

Comment: But the problem is that if I set `width: auto` for the labels than they wont align, I need to force a width to align them. But forcing a width will create some amount of whitespace, and minimizing the width may make a layout difficult to maintain (because the width will need to be modified whenever the text changes). I will accept your answer and appreciate the help, just trying to figure out the correct approach to the label widths, is it reasonable to set a fixed for them (and revisit it as needed)? or should they be set to `auto` and I should find a different strategy for aligning them?